# Why graphApi /calendarView/delta returns all items of a de event if only one was updated

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use graph API to check all calendar items updates.
I call `{{endpoint}}/users/:roomId/calendarView/delta?$deltaToken={{token}}` a first time with a calendar containing a recurent event with 5 items.
I backup the deltaToken

I update the second item of the serie and only this one
I call the `calendarView/delta` API second time and all the serie items a returned even if only one was updated.

is it an issue or do I have to set a specific params ?